# Macro to Calendarize Data

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem:**

I am writing a macro to do some data input for me. These data reports all have the same format (date in column 1, value in column 2), except the order of the months of data change from client to client. Currently I have written the macro to grab the data from another sheet and bring it into the current sheet. But now I need to write something to take the data and get it into the correct format.

Example: This client is organized from Apr-Mar (again, it could be any 12 month combination) and I need to get it into Jan-Dec, regardless of year.

Before:

```
Apr-14  37,645

May-14  47,000

Jun-14  11,600

Jul-14  33,503

Aug-14  38,550

Sep-14  36,063

Oct-14  39,246

Nov-14  30,315

Dec-14  28,403

Jan-15  25,799

Feb-15  24,302

Mar-15  27,873
```

After:

```
Jan-15  25,799

Feb-15  24,302

Mar-15  27,873

Apr-14  37,645

May-14  47,000

Jun-14  11,600

Jul-14  33,503

Aug-14  38,550

Sep-14  36,063

Oct-14  39,246

Nov-14  30,315

Dec-14  28,403
```

**Attempt at a Solution:**

I am hesitant to post it as it's incomplete and would be hard to follow. All it does is parse the first date cell to get the first 3 letters corresponding to a month, then check against 12 if/elseif statements. There must be a better way to write it, I just can't think of it.

Any and all help is appreciated. I'm sure a shove in the right direction would help!

Comment: Are the dates stored as strings then? Or are they formatted as dates? If they are already dates there is no need to extract info by string manipulation.  You could just use the function `MONTH()` in another column and sort on that field.

Comment: And if they are text strings, just sort using a Custom List

Comment: And do you want to order months regardless of years as the '15 months precede '14 months? This could be problematic in data consumption/analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating a loop that looks for "Jan" and gets all the data from there.

```
'Loop to dynamically calendarize data
''Loop returns 2 arrays, length 12, index 0-11, "electic" and "heating" in Jan to Dec format
complete = False
For i = 9 To 20
    If Left(target.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value, 3) = "Jan" Then
        For j = 0 To (20 - i)
            carryOver = i + j
            electric(j) = target.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(carryOver, 2).Value
            heating(j) = target.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(carryOver, 5).Value
        Next j
        complete = True
    ElseIf complete = True Then
        For k = j To 11
            electric(k) = target.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(9 + (k - j), 2).Value
            heating(k) = target.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(9 + (k - j), 5).Value
        Next k
        GoTo end_of_for
    End If
Next i
end_of_for:
```